# GWT - How to add more than 1 CellTables on the same page

Tags: gwt

I have a page using StackLayoutPanel.

In that 3 stacks requires separate CellTables.

Currently events I need to use are RangeChangeEvent, SelectionChangeEvent.

Now question is how to differentiate OnRangeChangeEvent from one another.

Comment: Er, use distinct RangeChangeEvent.Handler and SelectionChangeEvent.Handler for each CellTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source table is referenced by the event that you are catching. "event.getSource()"
 always gives a reference to the object that caused the event.

For example, if you have three tables, and you attach the same handler as below:

```
RangeChangeEvent.Handler handler = new RangeChangeEvent.Handler() { 
  @Override             
  public void onRangeChange(RangeChangeEvent event) {
    if(table1 == event.getSource()){
      // first table
    } else if (table2 == event.getSource()){
      // second table
    } else if (table3 == event.getSource()){
      // third table
    }           
 };

table1.addRangeChangeHandler(handler);
table2.addRangeChangeHandler(handler);
table3.addRangeChangeHandler(handler);
```

The above example assumes that there is no selection model specified on the tables. If there is, the selection model will be the source of the events.

Alternatively, you can just attach a table-specific handler to each table:

```
RangeChangeEvent.Handler handler1 = new RangeChangeEvent.Handler() { 
  @Override             
  public void onRangeChange(RangeChangeEvent event) {
      // Handle stuff happening to table 1
  }
};

RangeChangeEvent.Handler handler2 = new RangeChangeEvent.Handler() { 
  @Override             
  public void onRangeChange(RangeChangeEvent event) {
      // Handle stuff happening to table 2
  }
};

table1.addRangeChangeHandler(handler1);
table2.addRangeChangeHandler(handler2);
// And so on for any more tables
```

With this approach you won't need to worry about the event source, as you already know which handler corresponds to which table.

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work as event.getSource() returns SingleSelectionModel.

Comment: Right, I was assuming there wasn't a selection model. I will update the example.

Comment: I think its dangerous to query the source of the event for the object which fired it unless it has been set explicitly. 

The javadoc for getSource in Event class mentions that its type and meaning is arbitrary. It should be used as a secondary key to the handler.

Also it can be set when event is being fired using the event bus

Comment: @Guarav I don't think it's dangerous - but I agree it won't work if as you point out any object can be set as the source. I was assuming that the event is on the table itself.

Answer (score 0):

Were you setting the same event handlers for each `CellTable`? If so, don't. You can simply make a different handler for each `CellTable`. While it would theoretically be possible to detect the source as in filip-fku's example, it won't be if you are using `SelectionModel`.

Bottom line: you should not try to use the same handlers on multiple objects unless you **absolutely have to**.